# Generating a plasma via induction coil

Tags: pressure, vacuum, vacuum-pumps

I am trying to see if I can generate a plasma from an induction coil that is wrapped around a glass jar under vacuum. Tons of induction coil heatering circuits are on ebay for forging that can supply up to 1000W and operate at a frequency of 100khz.

I am feeding in 30V at 5A to my circuit with the copper coil wrapped around my bell jar under vacuum (~100mTorr) though I am not getting any plasma. Any suggestions? I should be able to ignite that with that pressure and the power in the coil?

induction coil link: [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1000W-20A-ZVS-Low-Voltage-Induction-Heating-Module-Flyback-Driver-Heater-Board/322396719383?_trkparms=aid%3D555019%26algo%3DPL.BANDIT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150817211623%26meid%3D45911a2f1fa74911b1b46e10b5efcd20%26pid%3D100505%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26%26itm%3D322396719383&_trksid=p2045573.c100505.m3226)

Comment: Sounds like you need a crash course in Tesla coil tech :-)

Comment: You can also generate a plasma without the need for a vacuum chamber, you can use what is called a One Atmosphere Uniform Glow Discharge Plasma. Google this for all the electrifying details.

Comment: Or even how lightning or sparks can be plasmas at atmosphere, though yeah I clearly need a crash in Tesla coils, though what am grossly missing here :L I thought the theory with an ICP was that the gas inside acts as like your secondary coil and couples to the main outer coil wrapped around the jar

Comment: Looking into this a bit more, i guess the problem is that I am missing the capacitive matching network to minimize the reflected power in the coil which is not allowing it to fully couple to the air inside